# Combining binary outcomes into one model

Tags: regression, probability, categorical-encoding

[edited post after comment]

I have n observations. Each observation can be A or not A; B or not B; C or not C. A, B, and C don't combine straightforwardly. Some combinations don't exist. Here's the truth table:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| T | T | F |
| T | F | F |
| F | T | T |
| F | F | T |
| F | F | F |

I can independently estimate the mean log odds of A, B, or C.

I'd like to say "out of A, B, and C, A is most likely, with an error of x".

But I can't compare these three estimates because p(A) overlaps with p(B), etc.

Comment: What do you mean by “on the whole”?

Comment: I edited the post to improve clarity.